# On flying with a backpack with detachable shoulder and hip straps, when best to take them off

Tags: air-travel, luggage, tips-and-tricks, backpacks

This is the first time I'm traveling with a backpack with detachable straps. Some insight from anyone who has done this before will be appreciated.

When do you take the straps off? After security checking?

How to carry the straps after they are detached from the backpack? Do you suggest I carry them in my carry on luggage or somewhere else ?

Is plastic wrapping the entire thing a better idea ?

Could the visible aluminum bars at the back concern the security officials?

Comment: Is there a "one right answer" for such a question? Isn't it just going to be a discussion about each person's preference?

Comment: @hippietrail I guess you're right, but is that wrong ? I'm looking for inputs for anyone who has done this before.

Comment: Well possibly yes because Stack Exchange is not for discussion and subjective answers. But let's see what the mods and others think, because it's certainly on-topic.

Comment: got your point. Changed the title and body to encourage more objective answer and less discussion. Hope this is acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

I have a similar pack.  When I fly with it, I usually remove the shoulder and hip straps (and put them inside the pack itself).  This seems better to protect them from getting damaged.  So far it has worked fine.

I haven't considered wrapping it in plastic as the airports I use don't provide this option.  On my pack, the shoulder and hip straps are made of specially contoured foam and I'd be a little concerned that they might get crushed.

Comment: Thank you, putting the straps inside the backpack is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would only take off the straps if the pack flies as checked-in luggage and in that case I would put them in the pack.
If so, you will need to do it before handing it in as the luggage drop off. If there is a security check before the drop off, you may as well wait till that has been past, but if arriving at the airport by car and your pack having a good way to lift it without the backpack straps, you may want to keep them off while packing, so you know you have enough space to put them in.

Even when shrink wrapping the pack I would take off the straps and put them into the pack. Less danger of anything getting damaged.

The only reason to keep straps on the pack when it goes into hold luggage is when you undo the fit of the pack by taking off the straps and you have to adjust them all over again when you put them back on and the pack is adjusted well already. In that case I would (and have) left them on, closed on the outside of the pack as tight as possible and hoped for the best, wrapping not available where I flew. I would shrink wrap in that case.

When using such a backpack for carry on luggage I will not take off any straps unless I need to do so to make it fit the size box for carry-on luggage, in which case I will put them away as near as possible and put them back as soon as possible.